# to.UpperCase skips the process where it should work

Tags: java, loops, uppercase

I am working on a coin toss program and wanted to allow a user to input either lower case or upper case heads/tails with toUpperCase(). But for some reason, after I input either way heads or tails it would skip the whole process of the loop and prints last statement. I am not sure why, because I had similar program and it worked just fine. Appreciate your suggestions!

```
    do {
        System.out.printf("Do you predict heads or tails for the coin toss?(heads or tails): ");
        String predict = in.next();
        System.out.print("Tossing a coin...");
        System.out.println();

        predict = predict.toUpperCase();

        int cointoss= (int) (Math.random()*OUTCOMES);
        if(predict.equals("heads") && cointoss==0){
            System.out.print("The coin came up heads. You win!");
            System.out.println();
            wins ++;
```

}

```
        System.out.print("Type \"c\" to continue or any other letter to quit: ");
        playAgain = in.next();
        if (playAgain.equals("c")){
            done = false;
        } else done = true;
        count++;
```

Comment: Well, you convert it to upper case and compare it to lower case, at the very least. No clue about the loop since you didn't include all of it, but make sure the string is precisely what you think it is.

Comment: try printing the variables or use debugger that will help you resolve the issue like this quickly

Comment: What happens if you write `"HEADS"` in place of `"heads"`?

Comment: @DaveNewton did you means predict = predict.toUpperCase()+predict.toLowerCase(); ? I tried it too, still not working properly. Or is there another way to compare?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem it skips the toss a coin process right to the last print where I ask if a user wants to play or quit. It doesn't stop the program though

Comment: @Rish what do you think the result of "HEADS".equals("heads") is?  Because that's effectively the comparison that happens in your statement `if (predict.equals("heads")...` when the user enters a prediction of "heads"---or "Heads", or "HEADS", or "hEaDs", or whatever.  It all gets turned into "HEADS" because of `predict = precict.toUpperCase()`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I also used substring() --> predict = predict.substring(0,4).toUpperCase()+predict.substring(0,4).toLowerCase(); to make all cases upper or lower. Although () is by default all upper, and substring will determine which case to change... I am not sure why it's not working really because I've used it before without problems... so confused

Comment: That gives you `"HEADSheads"` in `predict`.  How will that ever be equal to `"heads"`?

Comment: @KevinAnderson what is correct way to do? This is my 5th week working in Java :) I am still very green

Comment: If you're going to do `predict = predict.toUpperCase()`, then you have to compare with `predict.equals("HEADS")`.  Or you can just forget `predict = predict.toUpperCase()`, and instead compare with `predict.equalsIgnoreCase("heads")`

Comment: Thanks a bunch all for your help! I fixed it.. with your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals`. Then you don't have to think about upper/lower case (that you've mixed up, btw)